# Basic authentication with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, basic-authentication

I read a lot of post on SO on how I could be able to apply basic authentication.

I've produced this code but it does not show the log on page, only a white page is displayed. Credentials that I use **works in the browser**, so this is not the problem. My delegates are ok.

I can't figure out where my code fails:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    self.loadPage()
}

func loadPage() {
    let url = "mypage.com/auht/Logon.do"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 12)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}

// MARK: NSURLConnectionDelegate Delegates

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) {
    if challenge.previousFailureCount == 0 {
        authenticated = true
        let credential = NSURLCredential(user: "m.rinaldi13", password: "299792,458km/s", persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
        challenge.sender.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
    } else {
        challenge.sender.cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
    }
}

// MARK: Web View Delegates

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if authenticated == nil {
        authenticated = false
        NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Any help/tip will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution by my self, excluding all this boring passeges.

```
func doRequestWithBasicAuth(completion : (success : Bool, html: String?, error : NSError?) -> Void) {
    if let user = self.user {
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", user.login!, user.pwd!)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
        let url = NSURL(string: user.service!.getURL())
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let htmlString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                completion(success: true, html: htmlString as? String, error: nil)
            } else {
                completion(success: false, html: nil, error: error)
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(success: false, html: nil, error: NSError())
    }
}
```

Then you can evenly display page on web view in this way:

```
self.doRequestWithBasicAuth({ (success, html, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
       self.webView.loadHTMLString(string: html, baseURL: <yourNSURL>)
    }
})
```

Obviously you can (had) to beautify code, like creating a class for model User:

```
class User {
    var login: String?
    var pwd: String?

    func valueForHeaderFieldAuthorization() -> String {
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", user.login!, user.pwd!)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
        return "Basic \(base64LoginString)"
    }
}
```